# Unity claims that I don't have an object reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

it gives the error for the line 14 and 26.
I don't get it I just created the object at the line 8

First one is the code that runs the healthpoint obj and second one is the code that claims I don't have an object reference.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthPoint
{
    public float max;
    public float min = 0;
    public float current;
}
```

/

```
using UnityEngine;

    public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private float MaxHp = 100;
        [SerializeField] private float MinHp = 0;
    
        private HealthPoint hp;
    
        SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    
        private void Start()
        {
            hp.max = MaxHp;
            hp.min = MinHp;
            hp.current = MaxHp;
        }
    
        public void GotHit(float HitPoint)
        {
            hp.current -= 20;
        }
    
        private void Update()
        {
            float color = (int)(hp.current / 100);
            spriteRenderer.color = new Color(color, color, color);
        }
    }
```

I was declaring it but not initializing it. I needed to assign an object to the declared var.

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float MaxHp = 100;
    [SerializeField] private float MinHp = 0;

    private HealthPoint hp;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        spriteRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        hp = new HealthPoint();

        hp.max = MaxHp;
        hp.min = MinHp;
        hp.current = MaxHp;
    }

    public void GotHit(float HitPoint)
    {
        hp.current -= HitPoint;
    }

    private void Update() //health decrees will have an another effect
    {
        float color = hp.current / 100;
        spriteRenderer.color = new Color(color, color, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you creating the object? You are declaring it but not initializing it, there is a difference. You need to assign it to something either by using a constructor or by serializing the object to assign a reference yourself. Just change it to `HealthPoint hp = new HealthPoint()`. You would also need to remove the inheritance of the script from `MonoBehaviour` as it is not needed and using `new` on a `MonoBehaviour` is not intended functionality. I also believe you will get a `null` reference on your `SpriteRenderer` as that is not assigned either.

Comment: Another note as you are new to SO, do **not** post [`code as an image`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Format it properly for the reason mentioned in the hyperlink.

Comment: I get it now, thank you! I also forget deleting the MonoBehaviour so thanks again for reminding that. And sorry for the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
private HealthPoint hp;
```

with

```
private HealthPoint hp= new HealthPoint();
```

Comment: Alternatively actually rather make it `[Serializable] public class HealthPoint { ... }` and `[SerializeField] private HealthPoint hp;` and directly adjust the values in the Inspector without the need for creating the instance, your other fields or `Start` at all!

Comment: @derHugo is this a way to get "Properties{with getters and setters} " to work in the Inspector?

Comment: @Confused nope that is for serializing non-public **fields**

Comment: Do you happen to know a way to get properties to work properly in the inspector? If so, should I ask a question to get at that? I've never found a way to do it, and so don't use properties, just do all checking myself, like an old lady picking over fruit at the markets.

Comment: And, adjacent to this, not sure what's going on with animating serialized values, @derHugo... it seems doing so also animates (in the timeline of the clip) associated and modified values that are related, but not even public, just serialized.

Comment: @Confused basically everything that is serialized can be animated yes. And simply use properties with serialized private backing fields .. that's what I usually would do .. the setter will not be called though when animating these ^^

Comment: Yes, I've noticed this issue, and that changes in the editor don't call the setter, either. This is what I'm curious about... how do I get animatable and editor-editable values with setters working? I'm currently using OnValidate for editor and OnDidApplyAnimationProperties() for animation value updates. Both seem hacky and whacky, but they work.

Comment: @derHugo sorry to go off topic, and be asking about something that's probably been asked a million times. This and dealing with Structs and ScriptableObjects (in the Inspector) seem like glaring failures to consider what it's like to actually try to use Unity, by Unity. As does the entire new Input System.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237210/discussion-between-derhugo-and-confused).

Answer (score 0):

The following issue here:

You are getting a null reference because you have not created an instance of the object yet. Adding either `HealthPoint hp = new HealthPoint();` in the first declaration, or in the start function such as

```
public void Start(){
hp = new HealthPoint();
...
}
```

Will fix your error. However, I think you are using the start function as a constructor, which may work but is at least *odd* to do.

A better convention would be to edit your HealthPoint class and add the constructor there. For example

```
public HealthPoint(float maxHp, minHp, currentHp) {

this.max = maxHp;
this.min = minHp;
this.current = currentHp;

}
```

At this point you can also remove the Monobehaviour extension from the class unless you need it later

```
public class HealthPoint : Monobehaviour
```

->

```
public class HealthPoint
```

Now once you have the constructor you can just do this in the `Start()` function

```
HealthPoint hp = new HealthPoint(MaxHp, MinHp, MaxHp); 
// passing maxhp as the current hp because I am assuming you start with max hp
```